# How do I import Zbar into my Python 3.4 script?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, qr-code, barcode, zbar

I am pretty new to programming, and have never used Zbar before. I am trying to write a simple script that will allow me to import Zbar and use it to decode a barcode image. I already have a script set up to decode text from images that uses Pytesseract and Tesseract OCR, but I need to be able to decode barcodes as well. I have Windows 7 32 bit, and and am using Python 3.4. I have already installed Zbar and have used it from the command line successfully to decode their barcode sample. I have tried using >pip install zbar, but I keep getting the error:

> "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zbar.h': No such file or directory
>   error: command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2"

Getting the pytesseract OCR was painless but I have wasted a lot of time on this barcode portion of it, any help or alternatives would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I'd share my explorations and discoveries in relation to this problem, even though @ltadams21 has found a workaround.

---

**The short answer:** You can't. The [zbar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zbar) module is only compatible with Python 2. The incompatibilities are at the level of the Python C API, which is deep magic beyond my ken.

There's a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/zbar/bugs/86/) for this. In the meantime, use the `os.system` workaround that @ltadams21 posted, or maybe try [zbarlight](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zbarlight) instead? (I haven't tried it myself, because it says it only reads QR codes, and I need something that reads EAN barcodes.)

---

**The long answer:** You can follow along with these steps, which represent my best efforts to get it working, but (spoiler alert) it still won't work at the end.

1. (Re)install zbar for Windows (`zbar-0.10-setup.exe`), making sure to tick the "Development Headers and Libraries" option.
2. Download and extract the [zbar Python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zbar) (`zbar-0.10.tar.bz2`).
3. Open `setup.py` in your preferred text editor.
4. Scroll to the bottom, find the line that starts `libraries`, and insert a new line below it, like so (checking that the path is the same on your system as it is on mine):

```py
            libraries = [ 'zbar' ],
            include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/ZBar/include'],
```

5. Open a command prompt inside the extracted package and run `python setup.py install`.
6. Observe that the new errors now relate to `PyIntObject` and `PyInt_Type`. Discover that these are Python 2-only objects.
7. If desperate, try to re-`#define` them to use `PyLongObject` and `PyLong_Type` instead. Fail, because of course it's not that easy. Bang head against keyboard (gently).
8. Give up, and use the `os.system` workaround that @ltadams21 posted.

Comment: @ Tim, Thanks for the response

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying to find a workaround since I knew that Import OS wasn't the most efficient solution. I finally found a Python 3 wrapper that worked for me @ https://github.com/brettatoms/zbar-ctypes. However my program still wasn't able to scan a page with multiple barcodes like it could outside of my program, so I made a change to the wrappers main script and then submitted the change to the author, details at https://github.com/brettatoms/zbar-ctypes/issues/4. Anyways, I hope this helps if you still need a good wrapper

Answer (score 5):

Seven months later you accepted the best answer, a simple solution for
 **python3.4+** on **Windows OS** appeared. A ctypes-based wrapper around the **zbar barcode reader**, a package named [pyzbar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzbar). If you are on Linux, you need to install `libzbar0` but you said you are using Windows and the **zbar library** is included as **dll** with the Windows Python wheels. Today, all you need to do is launch:

```
pip install pyzbar
```

References for the package:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzbar
- https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/

Answer (score 2):

Forget wrestling with all of the wrappers. The easiest solution for me was to simply use

> import os
>
> os.system(r'D:\Winapps\Zbar\bin\zbarimg.exe -d d:\Winapps\Zbar\Examples
>   \barcode.png')

Worked instantly. Hope this helps anyone else struggling with that issue.

Answer (score 1):

As of November 2016, there is the package [pyzbar](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/). To import [Zbar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) for **python3.4+** on **Windows OS**, all you need to do is launch

```
pip install pyzbar
```

This is possible because [pyzbar](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/) is a ctypes-based wrapper around the [zbar library](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) that is included as dll with the Windows Python wheels.

Answer (score 0):

The ZBar for python says you need to have the ZBar library installed for it to work.  http://zbar.sourceforge.net/download.html

Comment: @ JJF - This is where I am hitting a wall. I have ZBar installed and working. I just don't know how to get the Python wrapper working in the script and talking to the ZBar library. I have seen a lot more solutions discussed for Python 2.x than Python 3.x. but my boss only wants python 3.x. I am afraid something may not be compatible with my setup, because when I use "pip install zbar" is finds the package and begins the install but I always get that error as mentioned above. and I have also tried the python Zbarlight.py wrapper and it gave me the same error.

Comment: I would just like to find a work around, or any alternative solution that would allow me to read barcode images, I just am really not finding anything after a whole lot of research. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution for 3.4+. First install pyzbar

```
pip install pyzbar.
```

Then the below should work

```
import pyqrcode
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image
qr = pyqrcode.create("HORN O.K. PLEASE.")
qr.png("horn.png", scale=6)
decode(Image.open('horn.png'))
print(qr.data)
```